# What is the right tool to auto compile the sass to css without Ruby?

Tags: node.js, sass

What is the right tool to auto compile the sass to css without Ruby?

Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Did you look at https://sass-lang.com/install ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *right tool*.
There are many options more or less interesting depending on your project.

Here is a non-exhaustive list:

- Using **[Ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org/)** and a command prompt
- Using **[LibSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass)** and a wrapper
- Using **Gulp** and **[gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)**
- Using **Webpack** and **[sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader)**
- Using a software (**[Prepros](https://prepros.io/)**)

---

If you want to test some **Sass online**, there are many tools too:

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)
- [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)
- [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Webpack with [sass loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader)
or Gulp with [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)